# Improving time and memory of a script based on numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to implement in Python the formula in the image. The set B is a set of real numbers -1 <= t <= 1. Also, F_2 is a set with the elements 0 and 1. y_i is the i-th element of $y$. This formula is part of an iterative part of my program. The number of iterations is about 10K (over x) and n is 32. I tried a pre-computation approach. That is, I precomputed all f(y) and put it in a numpy array, also I computed (-1**y_i) and put it in a numpy array. See code below. But even with that, the computation takes approx 3s for the non-precomputation and n=24. When I tried to n=32 I get some memory issues due to the big arrays. My question is. Could you help me to improve this code in terms of memory and time, please?

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
import galois


def precomputation_part(linear_layer_matrix, dim):
    y_shift = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: (i)>>j, ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint32)
    um=np.ones(((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint8);
    and_list = np.bitwise_and(y_shift,um, dtype=np.uint8)
    minus1_power_x_t = np.power(-1,and_list, dtype=np.int8)
    fy_matrix = evaluated_f_bool_matrix(and_list, np.array(linear_layer_matrix,dtype=np.uint8))
    boolean_function_0 = fy_matrix[0]
    return boolean_function_0, minus1_power_x_t

def evaluated_f_bool_matrix(and_components, input_matrix):
    t1 = time.time()
    mc = and_components.transpose()
    mal = input_matrix
    return np.matmul(mal,mc,dtype=np.uint8)%2

def create_ext_component_function(dim, boolean_function, input_lst, minus1_power_x_t):
    um_minus_minus1_power = ne.evaluate('1-minus1_power_x_t*input_lst')
    um_minus_minus1_power_prod = um_minus_minus1_power.prod(axis=1)
    boolean_function_times_prod = np.dot(boolean_function, um_minus_minus1_power_prod)

    return boolean_function_times_prod*(1/((2**dim)-1))-1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dim = 24
    f_matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
    boolean_function_0, minus1_power_x_t = precomputation_part(f_matrix, dim)
    ########The below two lines are executed several times
    x = np.array([i+1 for i in range(dim)], dtype=float)
    print(create_ext_component_function(dim, boolean_function_0, x, minus1_power_x_t))
```

[image]

Comment: Try [codereview.se] instead perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but here are some ideas for optimization.

1. f(y) returns only 0 or 1, correct?  If so, only compute the product where f(y)=1.  When f(y)=0, the product calculation is wasted.  This becomes very important if the probability of f(y)=1 is low, less so if not.
2. The sum is over all integers in 2^n-1, correct?  That would be a very large matrix if each bit is stored as a byte and especially if n goes even larger than 32.  I do not think precomputing is practical unless it is chunked.  Since you have a sum, there is a logical way to chunk across y.
3. You can probably reuse calculation of the lower bits of y as you calculate the upper bits of y since x is constant over the sum as a divide and conquer (helpful with item 2).

   I really wish we had latex here but:

   [image: recursive product]

   This optimization is not compatible with optimization item 1.

```
import numpy as np
n = 32
x = np.random.uniform(-1,1,n).astype(np.float16)

prods = np.array([1-x[0],1+x[0]]).astype(np.float16)
a = np.array([-1, 1]).astype(np.float16)

for i in range(1, n):
  prods = np.kron(
      1+a*x[i],
      prods
  )
```

4. Also consider using a different float precision to save memory.
5. Not a speed thing, but it looks like you are multiplying a lot of numbers which could potentially underflow or overflow.  Instead of calculating the product, sum the log of the element wise product and then exponentiate the total of the logs.

[Log-Sum-Exp Trick to Prevent Numerical Underflow](http://wittawat.com/posts/log-sum_exp_underflow.html)

Comment: thanks Mike, but let me know in point 3 where is the value of y_i. Could you explain that point a little more, please?

Comment: y_i is never explicitly materialized, but you can see that you have to evaluate both y_i=0 and y_i=1 eventually, since the sum is over all of F_2^n.  You could also write `a` as [ -(-1)^0, -(-1)^1].  Then  1+a*x[i] becomes both possible values of the typical element at i.